# Parse.com: Make my anonymus user persist even if i restart the phone

Tags: android, parse-platform

I have developed an Android app which user parse.com SDK.

I want my application to be able to persist with the first anonymus user logged on the device. With some walkarounds I have been able to make my user anonymus ID to persists even when i restart my app(but i'm sure it is wrong, even though it works).

Here is the code snippet:

```
ParseUser currentUser = ParseUser.getCurrentUser();
        if (currentUser != null) {
            // do stuff with the user
        } else {
            // show the signup or login screen
            ParseUser.enableAutomaticUser();
            ParseAnonymousUtils.logIn(new LogInCallback() {
                @Override
                public void done(ParseUser user, ParseException e) {
                    if (e != null) {

                    } else {

                    }
                }
            });
        }
```

With this code i have managed to make my user persist even when i restart my app.

The problem is, that when i restart my phone, the data is lost, another log in is commenced.

Their API does not specify it, but i'm sure it is possbile: I want my application to somehow persist my current anonymus user, even when i restart my phone.

Is there anyway to do that?

Respects!

Answer (score 0):

I think with your current solution and datastore enabled, it just might work. The local datastore persist the current user in a database locally, which should survive phone restarts.

https://parse.com/docs/android_guide#localdatastore

> Another side effect is that the current user and current installation will be stored in the local datastore.